# What is the "." parameter in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dit = new DirectoryIterator('.');
while ($dit->valid()) {
    if (!$dit->isDot()) {
        echo $dit->getFilename() . "\n";
    }
    $dit->next();
}
unset($dit); 
?>
```

what does '.' parameter mean in DirectoryIterator method?

Comment: Had you considered [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php)?

Comment: Dot represents the current directory, but yes, read the manual.

Comment: Yes @Quentin I am just a starter of php.

Answer (score 4):

The argument tells it which directory to iterate over.

`.` is a relative path to "the current directory"

Answer (score 1):

On every operating system `.` means the current directory, `..` means the parent directory.